# How to instantiate model in controller in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I am trying to use the model object in node through sequelize module.

I have something like these:

```
File structure:
models
  index.js
  user.js
controllers
  userController.js
routes
  route.js
```

==========================

```
models/users.js
//generated through sequelize cli
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    job: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return user;
};
```

`models/index.js`// generated file through sequelize.

```
controllers/userController.js

var model = require('../models/user');

var userController = function(){
    function createOne (req, res) {
         model.create({
             'name': 'John',
             'job':'manager'
         }).then(function(test){
             console.log(test);
         })
    }

    return {
        createOne: createOne        
    }
}

module.exports = userController;
```

When my route request `userController.createOne()`, I am getting `model.create is not a function`

I am not sure what the issue is and how to get model injected into the controller. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

**Update**:

```
my models/index.js //generated by sequelize cli

'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you define the models individually, then let the `models/index.js` properly stage these into the Sequelize object. Later:

```
const models = require('../models');

const User = models.User;
```

Then you can call `User.create()` and so on. The bare model definition file is not a complete package.

Comment: Thanks, but when I take out **user** from **require('../models)**, It complains **Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server/models../config/config.json'** +1 tho.

Comment: Looks like your database config is missing. That's a separate problem, mind you.

Comment: hm..I believe my database config is correct. The config.json has the right db credentials. I'll dig more. ty

Comment: Maybe that should be `models/../config` and that `/` after `models` is missing.

Comment: still having issue with the above changes...:( I will do more search.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have duplicated config.json, so it is database config issue. :D

Comment: There you go! Yeah, once you get your first Sequelize project working, take some notes on the steps needed to get it fully operational. It's easy to forget some of this stuff if you only do it once in a while.